# Managing asp Session

Tags: html, database, asp-classic

I have a code which allows session for my asp pages. However, when i try to use post form which takes me to another asp page, i will be automatically logout. Is there a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

```
<%session("cLoginId") = Request.QueryString("cLoginId")
session("Email") = Request.QueryString("Email")
session("cPW") = Request.QueryString("cPW") 
session("UsrId") = csng(Request.QueryString("UsrId"))  
UsrId = csng(Request.QueryString("UsrId"))  
Set Con= server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog="&session("db")&";Data Source="&session("SqlServer")&";UID="&session("uid")&";PWD="&session("pwd")&";"

mode = Request.QueryString("mode") 
UsrId = csng(Request.QueryString("UsrId")) 

cDesc1=CInt(Request.QueryString("c1"))
cStartDte = Request.form("sStartDte") 
cEndDte = Request.form("sEndDte") 
p=Request.QueryString("p") 
'session("cLoginId") = Request.QueryString("cLoginId")
cPW = Request.QueryString("cPW")  
'Response.Write "cDesc1=" & cDesc1 & "<br>"
'Response.Write "PW=" & session("cPW")  & "<br>"
cMsg = Request.QueryString("cMsg") 
'Response.Write "<font color=white>db2=" & session("SqlServer") & "</font><br>"
session("cLoginId") = Request.QueryString("cLoginId")
if cDesc1 <> "" then
session("cLoginId") = Request.QueryString("cLoginId")
cEmail= "cLoginId"&"Email"&"cPW"
end if
colorh3 = 1
%>

<%
sub  ChkUsrDetails(NewsRs)
    set rsUser = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    UserSQL="SELECT * FROM Login where loginid='"&trim(NewsRs("UsrName"))&"'"
    'Response.Write "UserSQL=" & UserSQL
    rsUser.Open UserSQL,ObjConn,3

    if not rsUser.EOF then
        cFName = rsUser("FName")
        cLName = rsUser("LName")
        cUnit = rsUser("Unit")
    end if
end sub
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad idea, since you'd be passing login information via a query string which would be visible to anyone. Rather move those variables to constants / pre-set variables which can't be tampered with by the user. As for the user's session when they've logged in, set it in your code *once* and then just check if it's blank on any pages that need to use it. You could redirect the user back to the login page if it's blank.

E.g. on `page_requires_session.asp`:

```
<%
If Session("UserID") = "" Then
    Redirect("login.asp?expired=1")
End If
%>
<!-- Rest of page -->
```

Then on `login.asp`:

```
<%
If Request.QueryString("expired") = "1" Then
    Response.Write "Your session has expired; please log in again"
End If

If Request.Form("submit") = "Login" Then
    ' check in database if user info. matches valid username and password '
Else
    ' display error message
End If
%>
<!-- HTML form would be here -->
```